# include config file from settings.gradle

Tags: gradle

I have two separate projects which I want to keep separate. However, sometimes I want to be able to combine them, briefly, into a composite build. Sometimes it's nice if I can do that for a while without affecting other devs. So, I want something like this:

My main settings.gradle, which would be checked into version control, would look like this:

```
// normal stuff
if (File('extra-settings.gradle).exists()) {
   // This is what I don't know how to do
   includeOtherSettingsFile('extra-settings.gradle')
}
```

Then extra-settings.gradle, which is **not** checked into source control, might look like this:

```
includeBuild('../anxml') {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.analyticspot.ml:framework') with project(':framework')
    }
}
```

This way I could add an extra-settings.gradle file to make a temporary composite build. Keep it that way for several commits without affecting other programmers or worrying that I'd accidentally commit my temporary changes to settings.gradle and then, when I'm done, I could just delete it.

I know about Prezi Pride and it seems great but won't work for our current build (we use buildSrc, rootDir, etc.)

Can it be done?

Comment: Occurs to me that I could make `extra-settings.gradle` a .yml file and parse it here and convert to gradle comands, etc. and that would work but a lot more work and not as flexible. Hoping for a pure Gradle solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

settings.gradle is executed against a [Settings](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html) instance which has an [apply(Map)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/PluginAware.html#apply%28java.util.Map%29) method so I'm guessing you can do:

```
// use Settings.getRootDir() so that it doesn't matter which directory you are executing from
File extraSettings = new File(rootDir, 'extra-settings.gradle')
if (extraSettings.exists()) {
    apply from: extraSettings
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Have some bugs that need fixing but will try this out in the next few days and report back.

Comment: Works like a charm. Much easier than I'd expected.